# Wireless devices can't see wired devices

Tags: wireless-networking

I have 2 netgear routers, a D7000 and an R7000.  The routers are located in different parts of my house and give a good wifi signal.  I have to use 2 routers because 1 won't cover the whole house.

The D7000 doubles up as a modem for my broadband connection and performs DHCP duties.  The R7000 has DHCP disabled.  The wifi is enabled for both on 2.4Ghz only.

The D7000 has an IP address of 192.168.0.1 while the R7000 has 192.168.0.254.  The DHCP range is set to go from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.200.

The problem is this:  if I am in range of the D7000 and use a wifi device such as an iPad, I am unable to connect (or "see") a wired device.  For example, I have a network music player connected via wired ethernet.  If I am near the D7000 I cannot connect to it from my iPad, while if I am near the R7000 I can.

I see no setting for "wireless isolation" or anything similar in the router settings.

Comment: What kind of bridging are you using? WDS? Are you using Netgear firmware?

Comment: Does the R7000 have NAT disabled? Which Ethernet port of the R7000 connects to which Ethernet port of the D7000? Which device are the wired devices wired into: the D7000 or the R7000?

Comment: Netgear firmware (latest).  The two routers are connected via the ethernet ports, not WAN.  The wired devices are connected to both the D7000 and the R7000.  The R7000 has Wireless AP mode disabled.